# awk, sed, for in bash: Print "Hello" + Name

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed, scripting

I have a list.csv with the following content:

```
"date";"Mr. Green Tree"
"date";"Mr. Red Apple"
"date";"Mr. Blue Car"
```

I use awk + sed to get the following output:

```
awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g'
```

**Output:**

```
Mr Green Tree
Mr Red Apple
Mr Blue Car
```

Now I want to use the same command in a *for loop* and add the string "Hello"

**script.sh**

```
get_name () {
    name=$(awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g')
    for string in $name; do
        echo "Hello" $string
    done
}

get_name
```

**Output when I execute script.sh:**

```
Hello Mr
Hello Green
Hello Tree
Hello Mr
Hello Red
Hello Apple 
Hello Mr
Hello Blue
Hello Car
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Hello Mr Green Tree
Hello Mr Red Apple
Hello Mr Blue Car
```

Comment: Do you have to use `for` AT ANY PRICE?

Comment: @Daweo No, I dont think so. I have to generate a mail with this names later, e.g: Hello Mr Green Tree, here is your information (...). So I want to generate a .eml-File for each recipient (e.g. greentree@forerst.org) ..

Comment: Then why not directly use `sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^/Hello /'` or `sed -e 's/"\(.*\)"/Hello \1/'`

Comment: This question is closed as a duplicate of a question whose accepted answer is specific to what that user was trying to do (call other commands within the loop) but is a well known anti-pattern for people like the OP here who are not trying to do that, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using your method...) Try:

```
awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g' | while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    printf "Hello %s\n" "$line"
done
```

If you know the input will be `\n` terminated:

```
awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g' | while read -r line; do 
    printf "Hello %s\n" "$line"
done
```

Bash loop from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185722/298607)

---

Or, if you looping over the file with Bash anyway, just do it all in Bash:

```
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2; do 
    printf "Hello %s\n" "${f2:1:-1}" 
done <list.csv
```

Or ***(most recommended...)*** entirely in `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{gsub(/"/,"",$2); print "Hello " $2}' list.csv
```

Comment: Only the awk script at the end will work portably, efficiently, and not corrupt the values being printed. You never need sed when you're using awk btw. `awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g'` = `awk -F ";" '{gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2 }' list.csv`

Comment: So... ^1 for the awk answer at the end but not the 3 shell loops above it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing it without even a for loop:

```
cat list.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' | sed -e 's/\.//g' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{print "Hello"" "$1,$2,$3}'
```

Output:

```
Hello Mr Green Tree
Hello Mr Red Apple
Hello Mr Blue Car
```

Comment: Working too, less complex code. I only can mark one solution. Thanks!

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you never need `cat` to open a file. `cat list.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' | sed -e 's/\.//g' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{print "Hello"" "$1,$2,$3}'` = `awk -F ";" '{gsub(/[."]/,"",$2); print "Hello", $2 }' list.csv`

Answer (score 0):

It works that way @dawg described, so I mark this as solution.

The suggestion from @Biffen is also working
[Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Code based on his answer:

```
get_name () {
    name=$(awk -F ";" '{print $2 }' list.csv | sed 's/"//g')
    while read p; do
        echo "Hello" $p
    done < $name
}

get_name
```

Comment: If you copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the problems with it. You should also read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some more important issues and to learn why not to do this. You never need sed when you're using awk btw.